# elasticsearch maximum docs in indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new in Elasticsearch and using free license of Elasticsearch. Adding docs to index from json web api with python.
But I have a problem.
I add new documents to the indice, but when the number of docs reaches 136264, it deletes the old docs.
Thanks you for your help

I didnt find max docs settings.